# colocar 5 aleatorios en matriz c#

Tags: c#

Buenas estoy haciendo un trabajo de clase en C# de hundir la flota el tablero es 8x8 y lo tenemos que crear con matrices y es jugador vs PC hasta ahí bien.. los barcos sólo ocupan una casilla y no pueden tener ningún otro alrededor y el pc debe colocar sus barcos aleatoriamente.. me podéis ayudar a cómo colocar los barcos aleatoriamente? solo puedo usar cosas sencillas que dimos en clase estoy en 1DAM y lo ultimo que dado son matrices y los tableros los cree con ellas.

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]. Haz el [tour] y lee [ask]: lo más importante aquí es _¿qué has intentado?_, y si lo hiciste, ¿qué errores tuviste? Y por cierto, tu pregunta tiende a [pedir que hagan tu trabajo/tarea escolar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320).

Comment: cree 2 tableros con matrices (el del jugador y el del pc)  también el colocar el jugador los barcos donde quiera y me falta como hacer que aleatoriamente se coloquen los 5 barcos del pc sin que alrededor del barco colocado no pueda haber otro

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega un [mcve] de lo que has intentado. [Sin código, es difícil que te ayuden](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

te adjunto un código puede que te sirva.

```
            //int[] tablero
        int[] tablero = new int[64];
        //For para agregar 5 barcos
        for (int c = 0; c <= 4; c++) 
        {
            //Generar posiscion random para un tablero de 8*8
            int indicadorBarco = new Random().Next(0,63);
            //Validar si ya esta ocupada la posicion
            if (tablero[indicadorBarco] == 0)
            {
                //agregar el barco
                tablero[indicadorBarco] = (c+1);
            }
            else
                //si esta ocupada restar uno al ciclo para seguir agregando 5 barcos
                c--;

            //Resultado: una matriz con 5 numeros en posiciones diferentes.
        }
```

Comment: muchas gracias con este ejemplo he podido completar el mío y poder seguir el ejercicio